# How to assign LINQ Query to a variable and then use it later in the code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

**Business Logic:**

I have three tables. `Referral`, `Referrer`, `ReferralInstance` with `many to many` relationship in `Referra`l and `Referer` tables. A candidate is provided with a Referral form where he fills a Job Request. The `Referral` form is posted by the user is shown to all the Referrer (aka Employee) tied to the requested company. Also the Employee in request company can choose to  `"Accept"` or `"Reject"` that profile (this detail is captured in the instance table).

**Behaviour Needed:**

Now when candidate adds a Referral Form, based on certain condition (mentioned below) I want to check whether this referral request already exists. If it already exists then I show a warning/pop up.

Condition 1:

When candidate just now posted a referral request. Then `ReferralInstance` table will be EMPTY, so I need to check if `CompanyId`, `CandidateId` and `SkillId` matches, if all these three matches to an already existing DB Record I want to set `hasPreviousRequest`  to `true`

Condition 2:

When candidate posted a request and `SkillId`, `CompanyId` and `CandidateId` matches. And many Employees (belonging to that requested company" Rejected him, but no one has accepted then I want to set `hasPreviousRequest`  to `true`.

Condition 3:

When candidate posted a referral request, and `SkillId`, `CompanyId`, `CandidateId` matches but one of the Referrer has Accepted him for the Job, In that case I want to set set `hasPreviousRequest`  to `false`.

Below is My Attempt:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckForExistingReferral(ReferralViewModel viewModel)
{
    bool hasPreviousRequest = false;
    var candidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    // CHCEKING CONDITION ONE   
    if (_context.Referrals
        .Any(r => ((r.CandidateId == candidateId)
                       && (r.CompanyId == viewModel.CompanyId)
                       && (r.SkillId == viewModel.SkillId))))
    {
    // NOW CHECKING CONDITION TWO
        if (_context.Referrals
       .Any(r => ((r.CandidateId == candidateId)
                      && (r.CompanyId == viewModel.CompanyId)
                      && (r.SkillId == viewModel.SkillId))
                      && r.ReferralInstances
                      .Any(e => (e.ReferrerId != null) && (e.ReferralStatus == "Accepted"))))
        {
            hasPreviousRequest = false;
        }
        else
            hasPreviousRequest = true;

    }

    return Json(new { hasPreviousRequest = hasPreviousRequest });
}
```

In above attempt, I made same partial LINQ Query twice. Either I want a better LINQ to check all the three condition at once. If not then I want to store LINQ Query used in Condition 1 and use it while checking Condition 2.

Something like below:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CheckForExistingReferral(ReferralViewModel viewModel)
    {
        bool hasPreviousRequest = false;
        var candidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var PartialLINQ = _context.Referrals
            .Any(r => ((r.CandidateId == candidateId)
                           && (r.CompanyId == viewModel.CompanyId)
                           && (r.SkillId == viewModel.SkillId)));

        if (PartialLiinq)
        {
          // SOMETHING LIKE THIS
                if (PartialLinq
                          && r.ReferralInstances
                          .Any(e => (e.ReferrerId != null) && (e.ReferralStatus == "Accepted"))))
            {
                hasPreviousRequest = false;
            }
            else
                hasPreviousRequest = true;

        }

        return Json(new { hasPreviousRequest = hasPreviousRequest });
    }
```

**EDIT**

`ReferralInstances` has 4 properties:

1. Id PK 2. ReferrerId FK 3. ReferralID FK 4. ReferralStatus

Comment: In _Condition 1_ you refer to `CoverLetterId` - is that supposed to be `SkillId` `?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for the typo

Comment: In your attempt, you are checking the PartialLinq twice. Don't you think the second check is redundant?

Comment: That is what I want to avoid. I am not sure how to avoid it. How to chain the LINQ and check the second half of the LINQ Only.

Comment: Your 2nd condition is repeating some of the first, and it appears you would only need o check the `ReferralInstances` table for your 2nd condition. What are the properties of your `ReferralInstances` table?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Added as an Edit to the question.

Comment: My confusion is if no one has accepted or rejected, then in that case instance table will be empty for that referralId. So, I just need to go off of "ResumeId, CandidateId and SkillId" to check for duplicacy.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I do not have ResumeId and all in Instance table. So I need to check the first condition and then only go for the instance table. Just saying.

Comment: Its still a bit confusing. You have said you want to set `hasPreviousRequest = true` if there is a match for `CandidateId`, `CompanyId` and `SkillId` but that does not seem what correct - I assume you mean that if there is a match then you then want to check the other conditions? (and I think you still have a typo since conditions 1 and 2 refer to `ResumeId`)

Comment: Really sorry, I edited it again.

Comment: So, if the skillId, CompanyId,CandidateId matches then I  need to see the instance table. If no entry is found there, then `hasPreviousRequest - Yes`. If many entires is found in Instance table and all are in "Rejected" State then `hasPreviousRequest - Yes`. If many enteires is found in "Instance" table, but one of them has status as "Accepted" then `hasPreviousRequest - No`

Comment: Therefore surely the 2nd/3rd conditions only need to query the `ReferralInstance` table (you do not need to check the `Referrals` table again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154001/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-unbreakable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckForExistingReferral(ReferralViewModel viewModel)
{
    bool hasPreviousRequest = false;
    var candidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    // Do an outer join between the tables on ReferralID and select only a new Anonymous type that has referrerId
    // and status. If no record found in ReferralInstances then set status to empty.
    var result = (from r in  _context.Referrals
                 join ri in _context.ReferralInstances on r.ReferralID equals ri.ReferralID into refsInst
                 where ((ri.CandidateId == candidateId) && 
                        (ri.CompanyId == viewModel.CompanyId) && 
                        (ri.SkillId == viewModel.SkillId))
                 from rs in refsInst.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                 select new {ReferenceEquals = rs.ReferrerId,  Status = rs == null ? "":rs.ReferralStatus})
                .ToList(); 
    // This covers third condition            
    if(result.Any(p => p.ReferrerId != null && p.Status == "Accepted"))  
    {
        hasPreviousRequest = false;
    }
    // This covers first and second conditions. If nothing found in ReferralInstances, the status will be empty
    if(result.Any() && result.All(p => p.Status != "Accepted")) 
    {
        hasPreviousRequest = true;
    }  

    return Json(new { hasPreviousRequest = hasPreviousRequest });
}
```

Comment: This one looks like it will do the trick. I wil try this now. Just out of curiosity, can you kindly tell me the 1st code snippet that I have posted in my question. Is there any flaw in it LOGIC WISE? Can you kindly cross check once.

Comment: I believe it still should work, it is just the performance and bad design. Have you run your code? Didn't it gives you the results?

Comment: I am still developing the code, not reached at a point to run the test. But I will try your solution soon.. :)

Comment: Ok, let me know if you still need help :)

Comment: Can we use Lamda style of LINQ instead of SQL style?

Comment: Yes you absolutely can. There is no difference in performance though, the code behind is the same. I asked whether there is difference in performance at VSLive conference to one of the MVP presenters, and he said no difference